# de-normalizing SQL Server table for performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, denormalization

Database design advice required!

Our clients are running SQL Server 2000 / 2012 as the server part of our client-server system. We have around 120 tables. Our design so far has been very stable, scalable and optimal.

Among others, have an Appointments table, a Users table, and a table that creates a many-to-mant relationship between those two. This way, for each appointment, we can set who of our users is supposed to take part in that appointment.

```
create table Appointments (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    StartDate datetime not null,
    EndDate datetime not null,
    ...
)

create table Users (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    UserName nvarchar(100) not null,
    ...
)

create table Appointments_Users (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    UserID int not null,
    AppointmentID int not null
)

alter table Appointments_Users add constraint FK_Appointments_Users_AppointmentID foriegn key (AppointmentID) references Appointments (ID)

alter table Appointments_Users add constraint FK_Appointments_Users_UserID foriegn key (UserID) references Users(ID)
```

Our problem begins when we query appointments to get a list of appointments for X time span. If we want to see a comma delimited list of users that take part in each appointment, we need a function that receives an appointment Id, and concats a string with participant names. This has some effect on performance (although not that much).

We are now starting to experience more problems with this, and we're conemplating adding another column in Appointments, that will hold the contcatenated list of users, just for viewing purposes:

```
alter table Appointments add UsersString nvarchar(max)
```

This will require triggers on Appointments_Users and Users, so that whenever a user is added to deleted from an appointment, and whenever a user's name changes, the string changes as well. We will still keep the current structure, because it is well-normalized and better for searches.

We are wondering if this is worth the hassle... Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Is it worth the hassle? Probably not. A "comma separated list of users" is a display thing - not a data thing. Your database should not be handling this in the first place, your UI should! Do you have approriate indexes on `Appointments`?

Comment: How many rows do you have to handle? Alltogether this looks not to heavy for me... How have you implemeted the concatenation? Anyway. on the first sight I would rather tweak your approach, then triggering around :-)

Comment: do you have any index on your tables? with a trigger you'll just move the perfomance problem from the viewer to the editor

Comment: By X Time span u mean EndDate - StartDate rt? If that is the case then why don't you create a computed column(persisted) called timespan and create an index on the same.

Comment: I would suggest you to optimize the Indexes before you denormalize a well-designed table!!! You won't believe how much Performance gain potential there is, seriously.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask another question, where you include the query whose performance you want to improve.  Include the definitions of the tables.  There are probably other possibilities besides denormalization.